# Count number of times a candidate has been voted for

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to go through a list that has been imported from a csv file and find the number of times a candidate has been voted for. I am writing this in python and I am not sure if I should create a dictionary and do an index search or create a loop that will give me a count of the name?

```
Sample Data: 
Voter ID,County,Candidate
12864552,Marsh,Khan
17444633,Marsh,Correy
19330107,Marsh,Khan
19865775,Queen,Khan
11927875,Marsh,Khan
19014606,Marsh,Li
17775191,Queen,Correy
14003692,Marsh,Khan
```

Comment: `pandas` would be your friend here. `import pandas as pd`, followed by `pd.read_csv('filename.csv').Candidate.value_counts()` would do it

Comment: I tried that and it gave me the results of: Name: Candidates, dtype: int64. did i i miss something?

Comment: Python comes with a specialized dict called [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

Comment: Thank you I got it to work!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use pandas, you may also use a [Counter, from the collections tree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). A sample of using this class is below. If you would like something specific to your problem, edit your question to post what you've tried and I'll edit this response to help you.

```
    c = Counter('abcaba')
    c['a'] += 1         # increment an existing value
    c.clear()           # clear the counter -- all values are 0 and you can start again
    c['hd1']            # should be 1
    c['hd1'] = c['hd1']+1 
    c['hd1']            # should be 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Or can do `pandas`, `pandas.DataFrame.groupby`, then do `as_index=False` inside, then do `count` for counting:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv(filename)
print(df.groupby(['Candidate','County'],as_index=False).count())
```

Answer (score 0):

First install python-pandas with

```
pip install pandas
```

Then you can use the following code for getting the candidates count county-wise.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('<path_to_csv.file>')
df.groupby(['Candidate', 'County']).count()
```

Answer (score 0):

From the standard library:

**Given**

A sample file `test.txt`:

```
Voter ID,County,Candidate
12864552,Marsh,Khan
17444633,Marsh,Correy
19330107,Marsh,Khan
19865775,Queen,Khan
11927875,Marsh,Khan
19014606,Marsh,Li
17775191,Queen,Correy
14003692,Marsh,Khan
12864552,Marsh,Khan
17444633,Marsh,Correy
19330107,Marsh,Khan
19865775,Queen,Khan
11927875,Marsh,Khan
19014606,Marsh,Li
17775191,Queen,Correy
14003692,Marsh,Khan
```

**Code**

```
import collections as ct


filepath = "test.txt"
with open(filepath) as f:
    votes = ct.Counter()
    header = next(f)
    for line in f:
        candidate = line.split(",")[-1].strip()
        votes[candidate] += 1
```

Alternatively

```
import csv
import collections as ct


filepath = "test.txt"
with open(filepath) as f:
    votes = ct.Counter()
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader)
    for line in reader:
        candidate = line[-1]
        votes[candidate] += 1
```

**Demo**

```
votes
# Counter({'Khan': 10, 'Correy': 4, 'Li': 2})

votes.most_common(1)
# [('Khan', 10)]
```

See also [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) on `collections.Counter` and [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) modules.